# Maintaining tectonic activity without oceans?

Tags: planets, tectonics

It is commonly assumed that terrestrial plate tectonics are a product of our oceans, and tectonic activity would not happen without oceans.

The question is, how can an ocean-less world maintain tectonic activity, to prevent a Venusian runaway scenario?

If this cannot happen, and oceans are required; I prefer not to have H$_2$O oceans. Is there an alternative fluid? The planet is intended to be habitable.

Comment: It the ice world acceptable to you?

Comment: @Alexander Not bad Idea, how much its temperature will be, can Ice absorb CO2? and what problems can happen to the atmosphere

Comment: Not sure about tectonic plates, but I'd recommend you check out Titan (moon of Saturn) if you're wanting a non-Goldilocks Zone planet with liquid on the surface. It has lakes of liquid methane, as well as a full methane cycle similar to Earth's water cycle. The main difference? Surface temperatures of 75 Kelvin. Also, because they're cool, check out the cryovolcanoes. :)

Comment: @BenjaminHollon I read about it, although it's interesting to have this, but I need it to have a nice temperature for humans.

Comment: @Khalid I must have misunderstood your statement about the habitable zone then? If it's outside of the habitable zone (where surface temperatures are 0-100 degrees Celsius), it will not be a nice temperature for humans no matter what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plate tectonics on earth are unique in our solar system and, as far as we can tell, in the galaxy, because of our oceans. Tectonic activity *could* occur on many different planet types, but Earth-like plates are being cycled down into the mantle nearly continuously. A combination of [rheological](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/materials-science/rheology) and geophysical observations suggest that the physical properties of [the oceanic asthenosphere are strongly influence by the presence of small amounts of dissolved water](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/253303432_Are_Oceans_Required_for_Earth-Like_Plate_Tectonics). In essence, the oceans hydrate and lubricate the plates for subduction, and also make them pliable. The edges of plates are marked by dry areas: the oceanic plates may be defined by a dehydration boundary that is formed as a result of melting at oceanic spreading centers. Where there is no water, the dehydrated asthenospheric crust forms the edge of an oceanic plate. Subduction is important for re-introducing water into the mantle. How do we know water is going into the mantle? Olivine in a mantle residue of a basaltic melt—the kind found in a volcanic arc—has about the same 6%wt water as what we estimate for the oceanic asthenosphere.

Thus it is possible that even if a subduction like process occurred on your planet, the rheological properties of a dry upper mantle would inhibit the formation of Earth-like plates.

It is unlikely that your planet would have terrestrial plate tectonics without a lubricating and hydrating ocean. And, while you may lubricate with an ocean of another liquid, you need to be introducing hydrogen into the asthenosphere if you are going to have a habitable planet.

I can not help with what other liquid would serve this purpose, sorry.